# Binding not working Checked List BoX

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi 
I have made checked List Box in WPF but the binding is not working correctly.I checked the List i created it contains the data in correct Format but when i bind it with the List box it does not work

only Last entry appears in list box number of item times that are in List

Checked Box List XML

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" Margin="18,100,535,74">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <my:RibbonCheckBox Label="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"  />                        
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Class For data holding

```
public class CheckedListItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

Button to Populate List Box

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  List<CheckedListItem> AvailablePresentationObjects = new List<CheckedListItem>();
  CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    item.Id = i;
    item.Name = i.ToString();
    item.IsChecked = false;
    AvailablePresentationObjects.Add(item);
  }
  list.ItemsSource = AvailablePresentationObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate your `CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();` outside of the for loop, and only initialize one instance of `CheckedListItem` which you edit 10 times. Only the last edit remains.

You also added this very same instance, 10 times to the `AvailablePresentationObjects`.

Try the following:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    CheckedListItem item = new CheckedListItem();
    item.Id = i;
    item.Name = i.ToString();
    item.IsChecked = false;
    AvailablePresentationObjects.Add(item);
  }
```

Comment: Ok this works well but what was the logic? like why we create new instance? when it gets Updated.and AvailablePresentationObjects contained correct Values

Comment: If you want 10 instances of CheckedListItem, you'll need to create 10 (new keyword). Otherwise you only have 1. You kept editing the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're only creating one CheckedListItem and then running through each of the i's changing that single CheckedListItem you need to loop through the CheckedListItems in List applying the relevant i to each one.